# Using JQuery -> QUnit in jsfiddle without external resources

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, qunit

I was trying to test a QUnit code snippet in jsfiddle, and noticed that if you choose JQuery under **Frameworks and Extensions**, a QUnit checkbox appears.  I clicked that, and added the required

```
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```

then added

```
// first tried:
test(function (assert) {
    ok(true, "Test");
});

// then tried:
QUnit.test(function (assert) {
    ok(true, "Test");
});
```

to the javascript box, and clicked run.  Nothing happened, and Chrome's dev tool's javascript console shows that QUnit is not defined.

Googling shows several QUnit examples where they've included QUnit.css and QUnit.js as external resources, but I'm wondering if jsfiddle's QUnit External Resources option is broken, or if I'm doing something wrong.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dfoverdx/xdc9xk68/1/)

Comment: In the console I see `https://github.com/jquery/qunit/raw/master/qunit/qunit.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. Looks like the jsFiddle guys need to update their link.

Comment: Should probably add an [issue on Github](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues) to get them to fix it. They should be using the [jQuery CDN link](http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.17.1.js), IMO.

Comment: I added an [issue](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/590]).

Answer (score 0):

See comment by @j08691:

> In the console I see https://github.com/jquery/qunit/raw/master/qunit/qunit.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Looks like the jsFiddle guys need to update their link.

As of 3/16/2015, this is the case.